# read parameters from json file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a JSON file like this;
{
    "name" : "maria",
    "age" : "40",
    "adress" : "usa"
}

and I want to apply a function which takes as arguments the name, age, address

my basic function is like this:

```
def get(name, age, address):
    print(name has (age) years old and a house in (address)
```

the question is how to feed the function from the JSON file

Answer (score 0):

For this simple `test.json` JSON file:

```
{ "name" : "maria", "age" : "40", "address" : "usa" }
```

We can deserialize the JSON into a dictionary with [`json.load`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/json.html#json.load), then pass the `name`, `age` and `address` values to the `get()` function:

```
from json import load

def get(name, age, address):
    print(f"{name} has {age} years old and a house in {address}")

with open("test.json") as f:
    data = load(f)
    get(data["name"], data["age"], data["address"])
```

I used [Formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) to insert the `name`, `age` and `address` into a formatted string. These are also known as *f-strings*.

It might also be safer to use [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) to fetch the values and give a default value of `None`, since you could get a [KeyError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyError) if the key doesn't exist. You can also specify any other default value.

```
get(data.get("name"), data.get("age"), data.get("address"))
```

**Output:**

```
maria has 40 years old and a house in usa
```

Comment: @daniel No worries. Welcome to Stackoverflow! If you liked this answer, make sure to give a green tick :)